# Api data extraction

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using an API and I get this result when i use the getJSON method. I have tried it in my codepen console and i get the same data but for some reason I can't figure out how to get to a specific text in the data.
so for example: console.log(data) gives me the entire result below. how do i make it give me just the exchange rate. 
`console.log(data[1][4])` i've tried several methods still failing.

```
{
"Realtime Currency Exchange Rate": {
"1. From_Currency Code": "USD",
"2. From_Currency Name": "United States Dollar",
"3. To_Currency Code": "JPY",
"4. To_Currency Name": "Japanese Yen",
"5. Exchange Rate": "111.28450000",
"6. Last Refreshed": "2017-11-23 00:24:23",
"7. Time Zone": "UTC"
}
}
```

What I've got in my JS:

```
$.getJSON(realtime, function(data) {
   console.log(data);
});
```

[image: The result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

`data["Realtime Currency Exchange Rate"]` and

`data["Realtime Currency Exchange Rate"]["From_Currency Code"]`

Comment: Thanks alot!! that worked! console.log(data["Realtime Currency Exchange Rate"]["From_Currency Code"]);